# What error handlers to add to my web app on asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, error-handling, .net-framework-version

I have this asp.net mvc application and for now I have added some error handlers.
I have 1). that checks if user input is correct or not;
2).If string.nullorwhitespaces;
3).If the user input exists on my db or not.
My question is: What other error handlers are there?
The idea of my web app is just asking for data and receiving them.

Comment: Depends on you web app, this subject is too board to be answered accurately. You can prepare for all known use cases exception but should still expect patching you web app a lot due to unexpected user behavior and etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.